# How can I fit a video screen on iphone using a plist

Tags: iphone, xcode, video

A video size is dimensions: **480 × 270px**. Codecs: H.264, AAC With subtitles and it fit the width but it leave black gap on iphone screen: top and bottom of screen.

Can a video be forced to fit the screen according to height dimensions to fit the screen (4:3 aspect ratio)

I'm aware of `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` in the contentMode. But I don't know how to use it in Xcode? If it is possible to have something similiar with `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` in a plist?

**See screengrab the bottom 3rd iphone is a preferred result.**

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/1full.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/1full.png)

UPDATE: **p.list in Xcode 4.5**

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/plist.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/plist.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "in p.list"?

Comment: p.list in Xcode 4.5 see UPDATE as above with p.list screen grab.

Comment: That didn't really give me any more information to work with. Anyway, if you're playing video with a `MPMoviePlayerController` (which should be the "easy" choice), it seems you need to set the [`scalingMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953) property to [`MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953)

Comment: Ok, where do I find MPMoviePlayerController? Is it p.list or Classes? I'm only guessing here.

Comment: I really think you should actually go through some tutorials on how all this stuff works. It's really not the purpose of SO to have someone walk you through developing an iOS app.

Comment: I'm not looking for a walk through. I am asking if a video be forced to fit the screen using p.list or alternatively, JavaScript that behave similiar to "UIViewContentModeScaleToFill".

Comment: No you can't, `plist`s typically hold some configuration pertaining to the application - they don't configure components. The component that plays video isn't an `UIView` to begin with. An `UIView`'s `contentMode` isn't the way to set video play back scaling. And you don't even use Javascript to develop iOS apps. You need to 1. find out what component you're actually using for video playback; 2. read its documentation to see how to scale its content.

Comment: mmm, I'm using (Phonegap) Cordova 2.1 framework for hybrid app (HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript) to run in Xcode 4.5 to develop iOS6 app using HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript as well as jQuery. In the last 12 months (or less) Apple changed its mind about strictly using Objective C only for iOS apps. We can use HTML through (Phonegap) Cordova 2.1 framework on the Xcode 4.5